# Make a collection available to two processes

Tags: c#, multithreading, serialization, dictionary, io

Hi guys I have a dictionary which has to be shared between two different exe files. The first application creates a key, then stores it in the dictionary, then the other application creates a key and stores it in the dictionary.

At the moment i do this:

```
private static void WriteToFile(Dictionary<string, byte[]> dictionary, string path)
    {
        Contract.Requires(dictionary != null);
        Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path));

        if (!(timestamp == File.GetLastWriteTime(DatabasePath)))
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(path))
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fs))
            {
                // Put count.
                writer.Write(dictionary.Count);

                // Write pairs.
                foreach (var pair in dictionary)
                {
                    writer.Write(pair.Key);
                    writer.Write(pair.Value);
                }
                timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                File.SetLastWriteTime(DatabasePath, timestamp);

            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is used to read a dictionary from a file
    /// http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-binary
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">The path to the file</param>
    /// <returns>The dictionary read from the file</returns>
    private static Dictionary<string, byte[]> ReadFromFile(string path)
    {
        Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path));
        var result = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            // Determine the amount of key value pairs to read.
            int count = reader.ReadInt32();

            // Read in all the pairs.
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                string key = reader.ReadString();
                //// The byte value is hardcoded as the keysize is consistent
                byte[] value = reader.ReadBytes(513);
                result[key] = value;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Then when I want to store a key I call this method:

```
public static bool StoreKey(byte[] publicKey, string uniqueIdentifier)
    {
        Contract.Requires(ValidPublicKeyBlob(publicKey));
        Contract.Requires(publicKey != null);
        Contract.Requires(uniqueIdentifier != null);
        Contract.Requires(uniqueIdentifier != string.Empty);
        bool success = false;

        if (File.Exists(DatabasePath))
        {
            keyCollection = ReadFromFile(DatabasePath);
        }

        if (!keyCollection.ContainsKey(uniqueIdentifier))
        {
            if (!keyCollection.ContainsValue(publicKey))
            {
                keyCollection.Add(uniqueIdentifier, publicKey);
                success = true;

                WriteToFile(keyCollection, DatabasePath);
            }
        }
        return success;
    }
```

When the programs generates the key and when we then try to access them, it only has 1 key, what am I doing wrong? The key and string is stored perfectly, but I'm just afraid that they are overwriting the files or something.

Thank you very much in advance, any help is greatly appreciated

PS: The databasePath is the path where I want to save the file, created as a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to say what exactly going on since you've not provided an information regarding how many items in dictionary and so on, but it seems like you've encountered some kind of a file access issue when accessing the same file from multiple processes.

You can use named [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) as a cross process synchronization object so before accessing a file you have to ensure that Mutex handle is released so you can aquire an ownership and an other process would be able to wait before accessing a file.

```
// Create a mutex
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "DictionaryAccessMutex");

// Acquire an ownership
mutex.WaitOne();

// Release
mutex.ReleaseMutex();
```

**EDIT:** New finding

Also you trying to write immediately after the read, so perhaps FileSystem operation is not completed yet so write failed, I'm not sure 100% in this perhaps .NET managed classes like File/StreamReader/etc already handled such cases but I believe it worth to double check in your case since is not 100% clear what is happened. So just try out adding some timeout like `Thread.Sleep(500)` between read and write operations.

**EDIT:** One more thing you can do is download [Process Monitor SysInternals utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and see which operations are failed when accessign a given file. So just add a new filter  `Path=file name` and you would be able see what is going on on the low level.

Comment: Good idea to do this but even with this File.OpenWrite will still overwrite the original data because that's what it does. :)

Comment: Yep but before writing a new key to a file he read all file content in the `keyCollection`, then add a new entry to a collection and then write updated collection to a file, am I missed something?

Comment: Ah yes, you may be right there. I didn't look at the code so much as reading what he said so I hadn't realised he loaded the old dict before resaving it. Removed my answer now you have pointed out its not applicable. ;-)

Comment: And surely a read has to complete before the program can continue? I know writes might get cached by the OS but surely a read must have finished or can the OS also defer the closing of a file after the read has completed?

Comment: @Chris : I do not know exactly, but from my point of view it worth to ensure since oeprations which involves interaction with hardware sometimes behave weird in tems of timing since Windows is not a realtime OS, but for File operation it could be not a case and wrapped by manager Classes like File/Stream/etc, but again I'm not sure since in the past encountered different surprises when interacting with hardware under the Windows

Comment: Thanks a lot, we fixed our problem and it's actually pretty embarasing to spend so much time on this and then find out why it did not work out. The path we were using to write the file was stored as a field and it was a relative path.. When we then split the project up into different projects and thus it wrote the file to each own project. So sorry for this! But the mutex idea is great, I will try and incorporate that, tyvm!

Answer (score 2):

Writing to a file in parallel is generally not the best idea. You have two options here:

1. Use a mutex for cross-process synchronization to regulate access to the file.
2. Forward all write requests to a third process that has exclusive ownership of the file and does the actual writing.

Answer (score 0):

So Process 1 loads the dictionary, adds an item, calls write.
So Process 2 loads the dictionary, adds an item, calls write.

You get which ever one writes second, and you don't know which one it will be.

Trying to make this work is way more trouble than it's worth, and it wil be as future proof as an inflatable dartboard.

Mutex at a push or a third process to maintain the dictionary.